# How to use trigger signals to set signals high after N cycles in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I have a `module(input:clk,reset,trL,trS;output:tL,tS;)`.

I need to implement that

1. `trL` = 1, `trS` = 0: Make `tL` = 1 after 5 cycles.
2. `trL` = 0, `trS` = 1: Make `tS` = 1 after 2 cycles.
3. `trL` = 0 , `trS` = 0: No change.

```
reg [8:0] count;
always@(posedge clk)
if(reset)
count<=0;
else 
count=count+9'd1;

always@(posedge clk)
if(trL==1&&trS==0(only in one cycle not always be like this))

after 5 cycles, tL<=1(only in one cycle);

else if(trL==0&&trS==1(only in one cycle))

after 2 cycles, tS<=1( only in one cycle);

else if(trl==0&&trS==1)

tL<=tL,tS<=tS;
```

Comment: You have `count`, what are you going to do with it?

Comment: I wanted to use count to count the number of the circles, like when the trigger signals are triggered, and the count is at a certain circle the output siganl would be high, but I was not sure if this could work..

Answer (score 0):

Okay here goes...

```
module trigger(
       clk,
       reset,
       trL,
       trS,
       tL,
       tS
     );

input clk;
input reset;
input trL;
input trS;
output tL;
output tS;

reg tL_d1;
reg tL_d2;
reg tL_d3;
reg tL_d4;
reg tL_d5;

reg tS_d1;
reg tS_d2;

wire tL_wire;
wire tS_wire;

 assign tL_wire = trL & ~trS;
 assign tS_wire = ~trL & trS;

always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin
  if(reset)
  begin
    tL_d1 <= 1'd0;
    tL_d2 <= 1'd0;
    tL_d3 <= 1'd0;
    tL_d4 <= 1'd0;
    tL_d5 <= 1'd0;
  end
 else
 begin
   tL_d1 <= tL_wire;
   tL_d2 <= tL_d1;
   tL_d3 <= tL_d2;
   tL_d4 <= tL_d3;
   tL_d5 <= tL_d4;
 end
end

always@(posegde clk or posedge reset)
begin
  if(reset)
  begin
    tS_d1 <= 1'd0;
    tS_d2 <= 1'd0;
  end
  else 
  begin
    tS_d1 <= tS_wire;
    tS_d2 <= tS_d1;
  end
 end

assign tL = tL_d5;
assign tS = tS_d2;

endmodule
```

Edit !!!!!
Hope this is what you are expecting

```
module trigger(
   clk,
   reset,
   trL,
   trS,
   dlya,
   dlyb,
   tL,
   tS
 );
input clk;
input reset;
input trL;
input trS;
input [2:0]dlya;
input [2:0]dlyb;
output tL;
output tS;

reg [2:0]count_a;
reg [2:0]count_b;

wire max_val_a;
wire max_val_b;

assign max_val_a = (count_a == dlya);
assign max_val_b = (count_b == dlyb);

reg cond1;
reg cond2;

always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin
 if(reset)
   cond1 <= 1'd0;
 else if(max_val_a)
   cond1 <= 1'd0;
 else if(trL && !trS)
   cond1 <= 1'd1;
 end

always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin
 if(reset)
   cond2 <= 1'd0;
 else if(max_val_b)
   cond2 <= 1'd0;
 else if(!trL && trS)
   cond2 <= 1'd1;
 end

always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin
  if(reset)
     count_a <= 3'd0;
  else if(max_val_a)
     count_a <= 3'd0;
  else if(cond1)
     count_a <= count_a + 3'd1;
end

always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin
  if(reset)
     count_b <= 3'd0;
  else if(max_val_b)
     count_b <= 3'd0;
  else if(cond2)
     count_b <= count_b + 3'd1;
end

assign tL = max_val_a & cond1;
assign tS = max_val_b & cond2;

 endmodule
```

Comment: thx for the answer, I was wondering if there is a way to control the number of circles, like make the 2 as an input and 5 as well, maybe input a, b; like this.

Comment: thx a lot!! another question if u don't mind. I was wondering how to set the time interval values as input parameters instead of inputs, such as :                module timer(clk,reset, trL, trS, tL, tS);
 input clk, reset, trL, trS;
 output tL, tS;
    
 parameter svalue = <<svalue>>; 
 parameter lvalue = <<lvalue>>;
        //where svalue means the short interval whlie lvalue means the long time interval, would this effect the result of the testbench?
        <<Logic for timer>>
  
endmodule

Comment: I see u assign the out when conditions and the count reaches the expected time interval, but is this condition \\ else if(trL && !trS)
   cond1 <= 1'd1; \\ needs to hold all the time? like the value of trL needs to be high all the time? I think the trigger signal needs only to be high at only one circle, not sure about this..

Comment: also I do not understand why u set the cond1 to 0 when max_val_a is 1, with assign tL = max_val_a & cond1, is this means that tL will never be 1?

Comment: tL will be 1 for one cycle because cond1 will go low and count_a will reset to zero in the next cycle after max_val_a goes high. So immediately when max_val_a goes high at that time both max_val_a and cond1 are high. Please observe the w/f dump for more clarity.